# Where does the file from Grapiz library get stored at?

Tags: python, machine-learning, graph, statistics, artificial-intelligence

```
#Decision Tree for lab using sci-kit - 2D
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn.tree import export_graphviz
import os
import pdb as pd
# main program
def DecTree2Df0732(): 
    Temp = [14.2,16.4,11.9,15.2,18.5,22.1,19.4,25.1,23.4,18.1,22.6,17.2]
    Temp = np.array(Temp)
    Income = [2680,4030,2170,4030,4900,6270,5350,7270,6500,4040,5460,3420]
    Income = np.array(Income);
     # categorical data - have to convert
    Sales = ['L','L','L','L','L','H','L','H','H','H','H','H']
    Sales = [w.replace('L', '0') for w in Sales]; Sales = [w.replace('H', '1') for w in Sales]
    Sales = [int(i) for i in Sales]; Sales = np.array(Sales)
    dotLocation = "C:/Users/vimst/Anaconda3/Library/bin/graphviz/"
    X = Income
    X = np.vstack((X,Temp)) # var x samples
    y = Sales
    # use sci-kit learn
    clf = DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=1)
    clf.fit(X.T, y) # do the fit
    with open('clf.dot', 'w') as dtf: 
             dtf = export_graphviz(clf, out_file=dtf,
                 feature_names=['Income','Temp'],
                 class_names=['Low Sales', 'High Sales']) 
    os.system(dotLocation + "dot -Tpdf clf.dot -o clf.pdf")
 # plot feature importances
    plt.bar(range(X.shape[0]),clf.feature_importances_)
    plt.xticks(range(X.shape[0])) # number of attributes
    plt.ylabel("Relative importance")
    plt.xlabel("Feature #") 
    plt.savefig("DTimportance.svg")
```

I do not have much experience and am just a beginner.
I want to view the resulting decision tree using the graphiz library.
This is a sample code provided by my school which shows a decision tree being created and a result pdf file being saved. After installing the graphiz to anaconda, i tried running the code but have no idea where the file is stored. Is it supposed to be stored at `C:/Users/vimst/Anaconda3/Library/bin/graphviz/`?

Comment: did you try to use full path when you create files ? ie. `-o C:/Users/vimst/clf.pdf` ? `plt.savefig("C:/Users/vimst/DTimportance.svg")` ? And then you should have it in `"C:/Users/vimst/`

Comment: @furas yeap just tried it but it didnt seem to work